# Javascript prototype set object or other prototype directly

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

In a code, I am seeing these two syntax to create an object which extends the Array prototype.

```
MyCollection.prototype = new Array();
MyCollection.prototype = Array.prototype;
```

Is there a difference between the 2 ?

Is one of those the right way to create a Collection object behaving like an array ?

Comment: Neither of these will work in the way you hope.

Comment: okay but what is the difference between the 2 ?